# onEdit(e) is not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I created the following onEdit function on Google Scripts to trigger the pullJobIDS function. The pullJobIDS function is working properly but the problem is with the onEdit function. I don't know why is not triggering. Can you see any syntax mistake?

The goal is to run the pullJobIDS function when any value in the Column with index 2 is modified different from NULL and in the Organisational Structure sheet only.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.source.getActive().getName() == 'Organisational Structure' && e.range.getColumn() == 2 && e.range.getValue() != "") { pullJobIDS() }
 }
```

I would appreciate any help with this.
Thanks

Comment: Well, does `pulJobIds` meet all the same restrictions that apply to simple trigger functions? If not, then of course it cannot run when it is activated by a simple trigger. You don't provide any idea of what that code does, so we can only assume it requires permissions that it does not have when executed as a simple trigger. Also note that `e.source` is a `Spreadsheet`, not a `Sheet` - use either `e.range.getParent().getName()` or `e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now it's working. I just removed e.range.getValue() != "" because it was giving me problems. So the final code is: function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Organisational Structure' && e.range.getColumn() == 2) { pullJobIDS() } }  and I set up an OnEdit trigger to trigger this onEdit function. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your script occurs an error at `e.source.getActive().getName()`. You can see the error by Execution transcript. In order to remove this error, please modify as follows.

#### From :

```
e.source.getActive().getName()
```

#### To :

```
e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()
```

#### Note :

- In this modification, when column 2 in the sheet with the sheet name of 'Organisational Structure' is edited, if the edited cell is not empty, `pullJobIDS()` is run.
- For your script, if some methods which are required to authorize are included in `pullJobIDS()`, please use the installable trigger.

#### Reference :

- [Execution transcript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#execution_transcript)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.